# How to configure build.gradle for testing in Android Studio with Eclipse folder structure?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, junit, build.gradle

I'm trying to add JUnit tests into a Android Studio project that was migrated over from an Eclipse project.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
```

I tried mimicking the current Android Studio default folder structure of having my tests in the `src/test/java/com/mydomain/myapplication` and setting my sourceSets to:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        ...
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test']
    }
}
```

but have gotten errors such as `Empty test suite` and `Package name does not correspond to the file path`.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, I eventually figured it out.

The directory specified in

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test']
    }
}
```

cannot be a subdirectory of the `main` sourceset's `java.srcDirs`.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
    }
}
```

I moved my test folder to the top level of my project's folder structure such that it looked like this:

```
myProject/
  src/
  res/
  tests/
```

and configured my sourceSets to this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        ...
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['tests']
        resources.srcDir file('tests/com/mydomain/myapplication/resources')
    }
}
```

and it worked. Any JUnit tests that you place in the `tests/` folder will now run, but I elected to place my tests in the `tests/com/mydomain/myapplication/` directory so that they group nicely when you are looking at them in the "Android" project view. You can see that's where I specified my `resources/` directory to be as well.